# How to tell PyTorch to not use the GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I want to do some timing comparisons between CPU & GPU as well as some profiling and would like to know if there's a way to tell [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) to not use the GPU and instead use the CPU only? I realize I could install another CPU-only [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch), but hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Before running your code, run this shell command to tell torch that there are no GPUs:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
```

---

This will tell it to use only one GPU (the one with id 0) and so on:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"
```

Comment: This seems to still give me an error of `UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system`.

Comment: @UmangGupta - I'm calling `.cuda()` at numerous places in my code. Does it mean that the code is configured to use the GPU by default? If yes, what change should I do to make it run on GPU?

Comment: You can replace `.cuda()` with `.cpu()` to make sure you code uses CPU. This is cumbersome but I think this is the easiest way. For the future, declare the `device` at the top and use `.to` to move the model/tensors to the device. For how to do that... see MBT's answer or this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332659/3236925

Comment: Once i do this, how do i get enable it back ?

Comment: @Salih you can say export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" to enable GPU:0

Answer (score 60):

I just wanted to add that it is also possible to do so within the PyTorch Code:

Here is a small example taken from the [PyTorch Migration Guide for 0.4.0](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#writing-device-agnostic-code):

```py
# at beginning of the script
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

...

# then whenever you get a new Tensor or Module
# this won't copy if they are already on the desired device
input = data.to(device)
model = MyModule(...).to(device)
```

*I think the example is pretty self-explaining. But if there are any questions just ask! 
One big advantage is when using this syntax like in the example above is, that you can create code which runs on CPU if no GPU is available but also on GPU without changing a single line.*

Instead of using the *if-statement* with `torch.cuda.is_available()` you can also just set the device to *CPU* like this:

```py
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

Further you can create tensors on the desired *device* using the `device` flag:

```py
mytensor = torch.rand(5, 5, device=device)
```

This will create a tensor directly on the `device` you specified previously.

I want to point out, that you can switch between *CPU* and *GPU*  using this syntax, but also between different *GPUs*.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 21):

Simplest way using Python is:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

Comment: I have no GPU, which is compatible with CUDA, and in my case this solution doesn't work (warnings still appears)

Comment: This doesn't work. I have one GPU and its still being used.

Comment: @Salih Same, on windows I have to set it to `","` (empty list) instead of `""`...

Answer (score 11):

There are multiple ways to force CPU use:

1. **Set default tensor type:**

   ```py
   torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.FloatTensor)
   ```
2. **Set device and consistently reference when creating tensors:**
   (with this you can easily switch between GPU and CPU)

   ```py
   device = 'cpu'
   # ...
   x = torch.rand(2, 10, device=device)
   ```
3. **Hide GPU from view:**

   ```py
   import os

   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
   ```

Answer (score 9):

## General

As previous answers showed you can make your pytorch run on the cpu using:

```py
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

## Comparing Trained Models

I would like to add how you can load a previously trained model on the cpu (examples taken from the [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-across-devices)).

*Note: make sure that all the data inputted into the model also is on the cpu.*

#### Recommended loading

```py
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device("cpu")))
```

#### Loading entire model

```py
model = torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on windows, setting the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable to the empty string will not do it. But it is in my experience good practise anyway to append a comma to the list, to

- make clear it is possible to have more than one number in there
- avoid accidentally setting the variable to an integer `0` instead of a string `"0"`

So, here's what I mean:

```
> $env:CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=","
> python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
False
> $env:CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
> python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a real world example: original function with gpu, versus new function with cpu.

Source: https://github.com/zllrunning/face-parsing.PyTorch/blob/master/test.py

In my case I have edited these 4 lines of code:

```
#totally new line of code
device=torch.device("cpu")



#net.cuda()
net.to(device)

#net.load_state_dict(torch.load(cp))
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(cp, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

#img = img.cuda()
img = img.to(device)
```

```
#new_function_with_cpu
def evaluate(image_path='./imgs/116.jpg', cp='cp/79999_iter.pth'):
    device=torch.device("cpu")
    n_classes = 19
    net = BiSeNet(n_classes=n_classes)
    #net.cuda()
    net.to(device)
    #net.load_state_dict(torch.load(cp))
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(cp, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
    net.eval()

    to_tensor = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),])

    with torch.no_grad():
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        image = img.resize((512, 512), Image.BILINEAR)
        img = to_tensor(image)
        img = torch.unsqueeze(img, 0)
        #img = img.cuda()
        img = img.to(device)
        out = net(img)[0]
        parsing = out.squeeze(0).cpu().numpy().argmax(0)
        return parsing


















#original_function_with_gpu


def evaluate(image_path='./imgs/116.jpg', cp='cp/79999_iter.pth'):

    n_classes = 19
    net = BiSeNet(n_classes=n_classes)
    net.cuda()
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(cp))
    net.eval()

    to_tensor = transforms.Compose([ transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),])

    with torch.no_grad():
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        image = img.resize((512, 512), Image.BILINEAR)
        img = to_tensor(image)
        img = torch.unsqueeze(img, 0)
        img = img.cuda()
        out = net(img)[0]
        parsing = out.squeeze(0).cpu().numpy().argmax(0)
        return parsing
```