# Pytorch 0.4.0: There are three ways to create tensors on CUDA device. Is there some difference between them?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I failed in the third way. `t3` is still on CPU. No idea why.

```
a = np.random.randn(1, 1, 2, 3)

t1 = torch.tensor(a)
t1 = t3.to(torch.device('cuda'))

t2 = torch.tensor(a)
t2 = t2.cuda() 

t3 = torch.tensor(a, device=torch.device('cuda'))
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All three methods worked for me.

In 1 and 2, you create a tensor on CPU and then move it to GPU when you use `.to(device)` or `.cuda()`. They are the same here.

However, when you use `.to(device)` method you can explicitly tell torch to move to specific GPU by setting `device=torch.device("cuda:<id>")`. with `.cuda()` you have to do `.cuda(<id>)` to move to some particular GPU.

---

*Why do these two methods exist then?*

`.to(device)` was introduced in 0.4 because it is easier to declare `device` variable at top of the code as

`device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")`

and use `.to(device)` everywhere. This makes it quite easy to switch from CPU to GPU and vice-versa

Before this, we had to use `.cuda()` and your code will have `if` check for `cuda.is_available()` everywhere which made it cumbersome to switch between GPU/CPU.

---

The third method doesn't create a tensor on the CPU and directly copies data to GPU, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Example to make a 50 by 50 tensor of 0's directly on your nvidia GPU:

```
zeros_tensor_gpu = torch.zeros((50, 50), device='cuda')
```

This will immensely speed up creation for big tensors such as 4000 by 4000