# How to run a pytorch project with CPU?

Tags: pytorch

A Pytorch project is supposed to run on GPU. I want to run it on my laptop only with CPU. There are a lot of places calling `.cuda()` on models, tensors, etc., which fail to execute when cuda is not available. Is it possible to do it without changing the code everywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell PyTorch to not use the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350/how-to-tell-pytorch-to-not-use-the-gpu)

Comment: @Gulzar Unfortunately no. The project code uses .cuda() in a lot of places which fails to run when cuda is not available. I suppose cuda is GPU.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the simplest fix I can think of:

1. Put the following line near the top of your code:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

2. Do a global replace. Change `.cuda()` to `.to(device)`, where `device` is the variable set in step 1.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job. Now I am able to run the project with CPU but with a different cause of failure: some operations are not implemented for CPU, so a ResNet model fails to run. That's the end of it:)

Answer (score 0):

That depends wholly on the structure and design of the code within the project in question. Usually there would be an argument to specify on which device to run on. You should check your code. It is also not advisable to run it on your laptop CPU especially if the project consists of a moderately large model. Good luck!