# please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu')

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-mining

I am running Python program, but I do not have a GPU, what can I do to make Python use CPU instead of GPU?

```sh
$ python extract_feature.py --data mnist --net checkpoint_4.pth.tar --features pretrained
```

It gives me the following warning:

> => RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.

The photo is the Structure of my Python project:

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell PyTorch to not use the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350/how-to-tell-pytorch-to-not-use-the-gpu)

Comment: I mean there are some answers (not only the accepted one) with code snippets of how to select the apropriate device to work on. In the second answer, for example: ```# at beginning of the script
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")```

Comment: I tried the code but it didn't work.             

use_cuda = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

Error =>If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.

Comment: Have you tried the code in the error message? Error =>If you are running on a CPU-only machine, **please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu')** to map your storages to the CPU.

Comment: I do not know how to try the code in the error message

`use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()`

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shahsohil/DCC/master/pytorch/extract_feature.py

The code is on this page

Answer (score 10):

I got into a similar error. Then by trying the following workaround issue is solved. (If your model is .pth or .h5 format.)

```
MODEL_PATH = 'Somemodelname.pth'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH, 
map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

If you want certain GPU to be used in your machine. Then,

`map_location = torch.device('cuda:device_id')`

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a smaller answer. To solve this, you could change the parameters of the function named `load()` in the `serialization.py` file. This is stored in: `./site-package/torch/serialization.py`

Write:

```
def load(f, map_location='cpu', pickle_module=pickle, **pickle_load_args):
```

instead of:

```
def load(f, map_location=None, pickle_module=pickle, **pickle_load_args):
```

Hope it helps.