# Problem with determinism : set a buffer size in the CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG environmental variable

Tags: python, cuda

I have problem of non-determinism with a LSTM model and I read that I should set a single buffer size in the CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG environmental variable, with:

```
    CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:4096:2
```

I am using Anaconda 1.9.12 with Python 3.7, and cudaToolkit 11.0.221. I have no clue where to insert that instruction (except that I know it is not in my python code ;-)

Any indication is most welcome.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 10):

Some references to the `CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG` environment variable are [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasApi_reproducibility) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/release-notes/rel_8.html#rel-811).

Setting an environment variable is typically something that depends on the operating system you are using, for example [windows](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/) or [linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/).

However, from your python script it should be possible to use a method similar to setting the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350/how-to-tell-pytorch-to-not-use-the-gpu).

Something like this, very early in your python code:

```
os.environ["CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG"]=":4096:2"
```

(and you may need to `import os` if not already)

Comment: Great ! Thnks for the very precise and efficient answers. It's implemented. Let's see if determinism increase even with LSTM and Conv1D NN ;-)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Note, you may need to restart the python console for this to work.