# where should I change the code to tell PyTorch not to use the GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch

As mentioned in [How to tell PyTorch to not use the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350/how-to-tell-pytorch-to-not-use-the-gpu/53267643#53267643?newreg=1763ca607d674ed18449fe6bfb87e40b), in order to tell PyTorch not to use the GPU you should change a few lines inside PyTorch code.
Where should I make the change?
Where is the line of code that needs to be modified?
I tried to find it but couldn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method `.cpu()` on any tensor or pytorch module transfers the component to the `cpu` so that the calculations will be made using it.

Another direction is to use the method `.to("cpu")`. Alternatively, you can change "cpu" with the name of other devices such as "cuda".

Example:

a)

```py
model = MyModel().cpu()  # move the model to the cpu
x = data.cpu()  # move the input to the cpu
y = model(x)
```

b)

```py
model = MyModel().to('cpu')  # move the model to the cpu
x = data.to('cpu')  # move the input to the cpu
y = model(x)
```