# Pytorch uses cuda despite disabling it. How to force it to use CPU-only

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried disabling cuda for pytorch following this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350/how-to-tell-pytorch-to-not-use-the-gpu) and a few others.

At OS level, before initializing python -> `set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES ''`
But when I enter the python prompt, I still see Cuda is available

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

A subsequent operation confirms it.

```
>>> a = torch.ones(5)
>>> b = a
>>> a.add_(1)
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
>>> print(b)
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
```

I can see that b also got updated. How do I force pytorch not to use GPU ?

Comment: Just because cuda is available does not mean you are necessarily using it. Also, I don't think your example here confirms that you are using GPU, it only shows you using a method for adding and it working as it should. b is a shallow copy of a, so changes to a will have an effect on b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`a.to("cpu")`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.to.html#torch.Tensor.to) to move a tensor to a particular device, in this case CPU. Then [`a.is_cuda()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.is_cuda.html) should return `False`, confirming that it is not on GPU.

The same can be done with entire models, etc., e.g. `model.to("cpu")`